# How to read relative file path in Jmeter using bean shell?where relative path is not in JMX file location

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}upload.xml

Note : In above example ,file upload.xml is not in director where JMX file is present.

I want to put upload.xml in c:/project/configfiles/ folder and for JMX files c:/project/scripts/ folders.

So how I can change the custom folder path in jmeter?

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for any form of scripting so I would recommend switching to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant code will look like:

```
${__groovy(new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() +File.separator+ ".." + File.separator + 'configfiles' + File.separator + "upload.xml").getCanonicalPath(),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Relative Path]